# executing programs without python installed

Tags: python

its possible to execute a python program on system where python is not installed?
I want to execute my python program like c program I compile it on linux and then I can execute on any linux system

Comment: Visit your profile, look at the questions you answered, visit them and choose the most appropriate answer, if any.

Comment: Are there any Linux distributions which don't include Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) to make Linux binaries. [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) is essentially the same thing for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use something like [Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) for Windows, or [Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) for Linux. And there is also the cross-platform [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).